# Why can't I reverse a linked list in this way without getting a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception

this is my first question here. This may be a dumb question but I am having issues with understanding why the order specifically matters when reversing a linked list in this way.
So here I'm reversing a linked list, which works

```
    ListNode prev = null, curr = head, next = head;
    
    while (curr != null){
        next = next.next;
        curr.next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = prev;
    return head;
```

which works just fine.
But why can't I do the following?

```
//edge cases:
    if (head == null || head.next == null){
        return head;
    }
    
    ListNode prev = null, curr = head, next = head.next; //change here
    
    while (curr != null){
        //line was previously here
        curr.next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
        next = next.next; //moved here
    }
    head = prev;
    return head;
```

Why does it matter that I set next = next.next at the beginning of the while loop, rather than the end? Why can't I set next = head.next first and then iterate it at the end of the loop without getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: Because you've changed what the code does. The previous line (to `// moved here`) is using the value of `next`. When you move that line below it, you're changing the value that it sees.

Comment: suppose `next` is not null which is assigned to `curr`, but `next.next` is null which is assigned to `next`. Now, `while` condition is still true(cause `curr` is no null yet), so in the next iteration, `curr` is assigned null and  `next` which is null, `next.next` results in error

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, you can think of the reverse operation as popping from the input list and pushing onto the result. Less epic code results:

```java
ListNode reverse(ListNode head) {
  ListNode result = null;
  while (head != null) {
    ListNode elt = head;  // pop into elt
    head = head.next;
    elt.next = result;    // push elt onto result
    result = elt;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make such a change, you change the state at which the loop condition will be verified. And this causes the issue.

In the working code, we have this loop invariant:

`curr` and `next` are equal. They are either both `null` or both reference the same node.

In the non-working code, this is not true, as now `next` is one step ahead. The corresponding loop invariant is now `next == curr.next`. So when `curr` is the tail node, `next` will be `null`. In the next iteration of the loop, `next = next.next` is executed, which is invalid as `next` was `null`, so this raises an exception.

It would work if you would make that statement conditional:

```
 if (next != null) next = next.next;
```

Or this would also work:

```
 if (next == null) break;
 next = next.next;
```

But both these alternatives are not as elegant as the original code, as now there are *two* checks to be made in each iteration (the loop condition, and this extra check). In fact, this extra check is just the repetition of the loop condition as at that moment `next` and `curr` are equal.